# Disable a EditorGrid row when a model attribute has been updated

Tags: gxt

Here's my request :

I have an `EditorGrid` which renders some rows based on its associated ListStore.

The `ListStore` has a collection of instances of my model which has an attribute called "markeAsDeleted" which is updated elsewhere in the UI.

My question is :

How is-it possible to change the rendering of the corresponding row to turn it 'disabled' when my 'markAsDeleted' attribute is 'true' ?

What's I'm expecting is a kind of a rendrer to add to my `EditorGrid` instance which updates the row as the model attribute is updated.

Thanks

Comment: I'm adding filtering to the grid so when the attribute markAsDeleted is true it won't be visible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hiding the column with filtering would be your best best.

If you set `store.setMonitoChanges(true);` then I believe it will reconise when anything changes that model in the store and fire an storeUpdate from there you could re-Apply your filter (if it doesnt do that automatically anyway);

example

```
store.addStoreListener(new StoreListener<BaseModelData>() {
  public void storeUpdate(StoreEvent<M> se) {
      store.applyFilters("");
  }
})
```

edit:
After reading the comments on another answer I notice you are using a Grid filter to filter the columns you could just as easily use addFilter on a store.

example

```
store.addFilter(new StoreFilter<BaseModelData>() {
   public boolean select(Store<T> store, T parent, T item, String property) {
      return !item.get("markAsDeleted");
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

GXT makes sure that when your Grid's store gets modified, the Grid is re-Rendered. So when other part of your application does update on the model, make sure that the same model gets updated on store EXPLICITLY.

You can use store.remove(), store.removeAll(), store.addAll() to replace the model with the updated one.

Comment: Thank you ! 
what's happening is that I added a filter BooleanFilter as a column that I hided and initializes its value to true. my row model has an attribute called markAsDeleted which is a boolean "binded" to that column.
I want that when markAsDeleted is false the filter reacts and hides the row or have the possibility to freeze the row to don't be able to modify data.

Thanks